# Unable to save data using pyarrow to gcs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, parquet, pyarrow, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to save a data frame to GCS bucket, and it fails with the below error:

> TypeError: **cinit**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'existing_data_behavior'

The code I try to use for saving the data is:
pd_df is the pandas dataframe which I am trying to save as a partitioned parquet file.

```
table_w = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(pd_df)
gs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset(table_w, root_path="gs://bucket/test", existing_data_behavior= "delete_matching", partition_cols =["group_id"], filesystem =gs,  flavor="spark")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

OR How to overwrite the folder while writing dataset as parquet?

Comment: Which version of pyarrow are you using?

Comment: pyarrow is installed from pip, and the version is 7.0.0

Comment: The latest version of pyarrow is 11.0.0, I would first recommend to update to see if that already helps (specifically the `existing_data_behaviour` keyword is relatively new)

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi, did the previous comment address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer in order for other community members to find this helpful.